# Slow search/filter algorithm

Tags: excel, vba, search

My problem is, my current code is pretty slow right now and i would like to make it faster, but don't know how.

I have data sets in rows, which looks like this:

[image]

I need to filter/search those values like numbers (for example show all >30). But some of the entries, like `30|32,89` are not numbers. Right now i am checking each value, if it needs to be split, like `30|32,89` in `30` and `32,89` and write all the values in a sheet. So i have a column, where all the values are numbers. With a second column, which saves the original row number, Like this:

[image]

After that i use advanced filter to get the data i need. I write it in another column. Using original row numbers to write values from the same original cell only ones, if several of the numbers in that cell meet the search criteria. And to do this, i save all the original data(20 columns and many rows) in a 2D array. Then i take only the values from that array, where the 1st index matches the original row number of the filtered data and write all of the values one buy one in another sheet in a row for each 1st index (this part causes the majority of the slowness). There are 20 values for each 1st index. So at the end i get all the corresponding data for the filtered items shown in one table.

Here is my code for that:

```
Public Sub numberSearch(srchCol As String, srchValue As String)
    Dim sValues As Variant, wRange As Variant

    'temp values
    cRow = archSh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.rowS.count
    Dim srchCol As String
    srchCol = "B"
    Dim srchValue As String
    srchValue = ">2005"
    '------------------

    'prepare sheet
    shSearch.Cells.Clear
    sValues = Application.Transpose(archSh.Range(srchCol & "2", srchCol & cRow))
    wRange = archSh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    shSearch.Range("A1").Value = archSh.Range(srchCol & "1").Value
    shSearch.Range("B1").Value = "tst"
    shSearch.Range("D1").Value = shSearch.Range("A1").Value
    shSearch.Range("E1").Value = shSearch.Range("B1").Value
    shSearch.Range("G1").Value = shSearch.Range("A1").Value
    shSearch.Range("H1").Value = shSearch.Range("B1").Value
    shSearch.Range("D2").Value = srchValue
    '----------------------------
    'spilt values, make all numeric
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim tst As Variant, c As Variant
    Dim s
    i = 2
    k = 2
    For Each c In sValues
        If IsNumeric(c) = True Then
            ReDim tst(0 To 0)
            tst(0) = c
        Else
            tst = Split(c, sepa)
        End If
        For j = 0 To UBound(tst)
            shSearch.Range("A" & k + j).Value = tst(j)
            shSearch.Range("B" & k + j).Value = i
        Next j
        i = i + 1
        k = k + UBound(tst) - LBound(tst) + 1
    Next
    '--------------------------------
    'filter data
    Dim rgData As Range, rgCrit As Range, rgOut As Range
    Set rgData = shSearch.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgCrit = shSearch.Range("D1").CurrentRegion
    Set rgOut = shSearch.Range("G1").CurrentRegion
    rgData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rgCrit, rgOut
    '---------------------------------
    'write searched data
    Dim searchColVal As Variant
    searchColVal = Application.Transpose(shSearch.Range("H1:H" & shSearch.Cells(rowS.count, 8).End(xlUp).row))
    Dim tempItem As Long
    tempItem = 0
    k = 4
    tmpSh.Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Clear
    archSh.Range("A1:T1").Copy tmpSh.Range("A4")
    For i = 2 To UBound(searchColVal)
        If tempItem <> searchColVal(i) Then
            ReDim Preserve filterRow(1 To k - 3)
            filterRow(k - 3) = searchColVal(i)
            k = k + 1
            tempItem = searchColVal(i)
            For j = 1 To UBound(wRange, 2)
                tmpSh.Cells(k, j).Value = wRange(searchColVal(i), j)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    '----------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Can anybody help me with speeding up this mess please? Ty in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `Advanced Filter` and formula criteria.

We use `FILTERXML` *(available in Excel 2013+)* to split the text values.
We also is the `ISNUMBER` function to exclude the text values from being cast as `TRUE` by the comparison in the first formula.

*And the Advanced Filter has an option to write the results elsewhere*

For your example, the two formulas might be:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A9),A9>30)
=OR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A9,"|","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s")>30)
```

#### Before Filter

[image]

#### After Filter

[image]

Or, if you change the criteria in both formulas for `>30` to `<30`

[image]

Depending on what you need, you could certainly use VBA to generate the relevant formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This scans down the column, splits the cell value into an array then uses [Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) to apply the search value.

```vb
Public Sub numberSearch2()

    Const COL_FILTER = "B"
    Const srchValue = ">2005"

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, WsTarget, t0 As Single
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long, iTargetRow As Long
    Dim ar As Variant, i As Integer
    t0 = timer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set WsTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
    WsTarget.Cells.Clear
    wsSource.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy WsTarget.Range("A1")
    iTargetRow = 2

    With wsSource
        iLastRow = .Range(COL_FILTER & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For iRow = 2 To iLastRow
            ar = Split(.Cells(iRow, COL_FILTER), "|")
            For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                If Evaluate(ar(i) & srchValue) Then
                    wsSource.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Copy WsTarget.Cells(iTargetRow, 1)
                    iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
                    i = UBound(ar) ' exit loop
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

    MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows read " & vbCr & _
           iTargetRow - 2 & " rows written", vbInformation, "Completed in " & Int(timer - t0) & " secs"

End Sub
```